# How to scanf each number into an array slot?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Im trying to scan each single number into each into an array slot. So the first digit will go to slot 1 and the second would go to slot 2 etx. How do I do this? With the code below all of the numbers get stored in slot 1. I want to enter all the numbers togther, no 1 number at a time. Please can someone tell me how to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lotoNumbers[7];

    printf("Please enter todays winning ticket number:");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &lotoNumbers[1],
                            &lotoNumbers[2],
                            &lotoNumbers[3],
                            &lotoNumbers[4],
                            &lotoNumbers[5],
                            &lotoNumbers[6],
                            &lotoNumbers[7]);

    printf("Your loto ticket number is: %d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
                lotoNumbers[1],
                lotoNumbers[2],
                lotoNumbers[3],
                lotoNumbers[4],
                lotoNumbers[5],
                lotoNumbers[6],
                lotoNumbers[7]);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated note: in C, array indices start from `0` and go to `n - 1`, where `n` is the size of the array. You have it going from `1` to `7`, it should be from `0` to `6`.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This code below will let you get all at a time separated by spaces...
Also, your code start counting from 1 up to N, you must go from 0 up to N - 1

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{

    int lotoNumbers[7];


    printf("Please enter todays winning ticket number:");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d",&lotoNumbers[0],&lotoNumbers[1],&lotoNumbers[2],&lotoNumbers[3],&lotoNumbers[4],&lotoNumbers[5],&lotoNumbers[6]);
// scanf("%d.%d.%d.%d.%d.%d.%d",&lotoNumbers[0],&lotoNumbers[1],&lotoNumbers[2],&lotoNumbers[3],&lotoNumbers[4],&lotoNumbers[5],&lotoNumbers[6]);

    printf("Your loto ticket number is: %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", lotoNumbers[0], lotoNumbers[1], lotoNumbers[2], lotoNumbers[3], lotoNumbers[4], lotoNumbers[5], lotoNumbers[6]);

return(0);
}
```

Look at the commented scanf... it will work if you enter the digits separated by a . :

```
    312.832.3278.3217.3123.7812.8
```

but if you glue all %d's together how will it know if the number 145 is just a single number or 1, 4, 5 or 14, 5 or 1, 45...

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without the spaces?

Comment: To read numbers that contain more than 1 digit, there must be some kind of separator between the numbers.  Personally, I would use getch(), saving each char in an array/string until a non digit is read, convert the resulting string to a number, place the resulting number into lotoNumbers[], use getch() and toss the result until a digit is again read, then loop, starting at 'saving each char'

Answer (score 1):

Use `"%1d"`.  This limits the width of the scanning to 1 `char`.

```
int lotoNumbers[7];
if (scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &lotoNumbers[0], &lotoNumbers[1],
    &lotoNumbers[2], &lotoNumbers[3], &lotoNumbers[4], &lotoNumbers[5],
    &lotoNumbers[6]) == 7) {
  GoodToGo();
}
```

Check `scanf()` results and start indexing at 0.

Answer (score 0):

instead of scanf, use getchar() function to get single char. getchar() or getch() function do not require to press ENTER after input. here's the code  -

```
int loto[7];

int i;
char c;

for(i=0;i<7;i++){

    c=getchar();

    int temp=c-'0';

    loto[i]=temp;    
}
```

Comment: What if I want to store *numbers* and not *digits* ? I can hardly find the '42' character in my ASCII table... :)

Comment: for numbers getchar() would not work. this question was specifically asked for digits

Comment: The OP used "digits" once, and "numbers" 4 times. Plus : we can assume a lottery ticket isn't composed of digits only (though it'd be very nice !). I think it's worth mentioning anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int lotoNumbers[7];
    printf("Please enter todays winning ticket number:");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&lotoNumbers[0],&lotoNumbers[1],&lotoNumbers[2],&lotoNumbers[3],&lotoNumbers[4],&lotoNumbers[5],&lotoNumbers[6]);

    printf("Your loto ticket number is:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",lotoNumbers[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the spaces?